# API Management GIT Flow

Tags: git, azure-api-management, git-flow

I want to implement an API Management GIT flow process that works something like this

[image]

Basically I have a GIT repository that stores configuration of an APIM instance.  Development teams can create feature branches from the Develop branch using normal GIT techniques

Then at the click of a button a new APIM instance is created (DEV 5 in this picture).  I already have an ARM template inside a release pipeline that will create this fresh instance

What I need to do next is to take the Configuration from the FEATURE Branch and push that to the newly created DEV 5 instance.  Is there an ARM template for such a thing - or some scripts I can use?

From there the Dev 5 team will make their changes manually and push back to their feature branch

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked that resource?:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit

I'm also on this process of implementation,I even have a question here, asap I to implement I'll answer here